# Automatically add 1 until reach a certain number rather than listing whole set of numbers in an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have a list of numbers in an array. One by one with each number in the array, a request is made to an external website (with the number being a url variable) and the contents of the webpage is displayed.

Rather than listing all the numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9) in the array, how can I add 1 every time a request is made to test2.php until the number is 9 (as this is the last in the array)?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$({}).queue("ajax", $.map(arr, function(item, i) {
  return function(next) {
    return $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test2.php",
              data: {n:item}
           })
           .then(function(data) { 
             $("#here").append(data);  
             next();
           });

  }
})).dequeue("ajax")
```

test2.php

```
if (isset($_POST["n"])) {
  $content = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com?id=" . $_POST["n"]);
  echo $content
}
```

Comment: just send `n:9` as data in your AJAX request, then in your PHP create a loop from 1 to 9

Comment: Why don't you just run a GET against `https://www.example.com/?id=<item>`?

Comment: @ChrisMagnussen Are you talking about pure PHP? If yes, then I can't as the code I have at the moment displays the pages content every time a request is made, rather than having to wait for all the requests to be made.

Comment: @RST How would I loop the numbers and send one in each request?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just loop?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test2.php",
        data: {n:arr[i]}
    })
    .then(function(data) { 
        $("#here").append(data);
    });

}
```

Of course, the display order is left to chance like this, whereas your original function maintains the array order. If that's a requirement, then you'd want to create an array of functions in the loop and then pass it to the $.queue() function, like so:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var q = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    q.push((function(i){
        return function(next){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test2.php",
                data: {n:arr[i]}
            })
            .then(function(data) { 
                $("#here").append(data);
                next();
            });
        }
    })(i));
}
$({}).queue("ajax", q).dequeue("ajax");
```

Removing the array and just using the loop index:

```
var q = [];
var q_start = 1;
var q_end = 9;

for(var i = q_start; i <= q_end; i++ ) {
    q.push((function(i){
        return function(next){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "_test2.php",
                data: {n:i}
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                $("#here").append(data);
                next();
            });
        }
    })(i));
}
$({}).queue("ajax", q).dequeue("ajax");
```

Comment: Do I need to keep `var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];`?

Comment: Remember I only want `var arr = 1` and then to increase the number every time a request is made

Comment: Sure, you can just use the loop counter. I assumed there was some importance to the array, and it leaves room for configuration/customization. I'll add another version of the code to my answer, give me a few minutes and it'll be up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
$({}).queue("ajax", $.map(new Array(9), function(item, i) { // ← notice here
  return function(next) {
    return $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test2.php",
              data: {n: i + 1 } // ← and here
           })
           .then(function(data) { 
             $("#here").append(data);  
             next();
           });

  }
})).dequeue("ajax");
```

What changed is that I used the `index (i) + 1` reference instead of the item. This works because `i` starts from 0, and will increment by 1 until it reacher `array.length - 1`, and in this case I didn't need a for loop and passed a an array of 9 undefined elements (`new Array(9)`) as parameters in `$.map`

The code is very unsemantically correct, but it works for your purposes without changing too much of your code

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
var i = 1;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function callAjax() {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "test2.php",
           data: {n:i},
           success:function(data){
             $("#here").append(data);  
             if ( i++ < 9 ) {
                callAjax();
            }
           }
        });         
    }
    callAjax();
});
```

Please Make sure your have #here div in html

Comment: jquery-1.12.4.js:569 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 1

Comment: Also, JavaScript isn't my best coding language (I got most of the code from another question) - are you able to incorporate my code in your answer (the contents being displayed after each request)?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this but following your scenario, your PHP file could look like:

```
if (isset($_POST["n"])) {
  $pages = array();
  $number = intval($_POST['n']);

  if ($number > 0 ) {
    for( $i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++ ) {
      $pages[] = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com?id=" . $i);
    }
  }
  return $pages;
}
```

Then in the AJAX success function you take care of displaying the collected content.

Comment: I was really hoping to keep my PHP as it is and just amend the JS